# .net c# generate .jar

Tags: .net, visual-studio, jar

I need to generate .jar from .Net project. I've tried to follow [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1f84c9f9-d006-4a26-9657-e3ea07fee706/how-to-read-and-create-a-jarfile-?forum=csharpgeneral). The problem is i need to add reference vjslib, i couldn't succeed this. I couldn't find it. Also, when i try to add java via nuget package manager, i get error "couldn't install package java .net framework". How can i add java packages to .Net framework?

Answer (score 1):

you can use IKVM.Net Library but important JAR Files which is to be converted to DLL should be complied with JAVA JDK 1.7 or below.

```
ikvmc -target:library -out:<<outputFileName>>.dll -recurse:<<jarFilesPath>>/*.jar"
```

example

```
ikvmc -target:library -out:JarToDLL.dll -recurse:"./*.jar"
```

if JAR files will compile with JDK 1.8 or above. IKVM currently does not support converting

Comment: How should i run this code command? Should i install ikvm and run the command on cmd? What i want to do is basically i've a .net console app and it should be executable on windows, linux and mac. That is why i thought if i could generate .jar from the .net project, i would use it in all os.